Snakemake handle variable input datasets
I'm just getting started with Snakemake and I can't make sense of wildcards. My workflow will have an input data directory with the following structure:
data/
├─ somedataset/
│  ├─ somesubset.csv
│  ├─ someothersubset.csv
├─ seconddataset/
│  ├─ somesubsetofsecond.csv
│  ├─ yetanothersubset.csv
│  ├─ andyetanothersubset.csv

Without specifying the possible datasets and subsets in my configuration, I want to have the output structure below. So every input subset gets split into a fixed number of partitions by a script which receives the list of input files.
output/
├─ somedataset/
│  ├─ somesubset_01.csv
│  ├─ somesubset_02.csv
│  ├─ someothersubset_01.csv
│  ├─ someothersubset_02.csv
├─ seconddataset/
│  ├─ somesubsetofsecond_01.csv
│  ├─ somesubsetofsecond_02.csv
│  ├─ yetanothersubset_01.csv
│  ├─ yetanothersubset_02.csv
│  ├─ andyetanothersubset_01.csv
│  ├─ andyetanothersubset_02.csv

How can I achieve this with wildcards? I have tried this for example:
wildcard_constraints:
    dataset=r"\w+",
    subset=r"\w+"


rule test:
    input:
        "data/{dataset}/{subset}.csv"
    output:
        expand("output/{dataset}/{subset}_{partition}.csv", partition=["01", "02"])
    shell:
        "python scripts/test.py {input}"

But this results in `No values given for wildcard 'dataset'.
Alternatively, when I try this:
datasets = ["somedataset", "seconddataset"]

for dataset in datasets:
    rule:
        name: f"process_{dataset}"
        input:
            expand("data/{dataset}/{subset}.csv", dataset=[dataset], subset=subsets)
        output:
            expand("output/{dataset}/{subset}_{partition}.csv", dataset=[dataset], subset=subsets, partition=["01", "02"])
        shell:
            "python scripts/test.py {input}"

I get No rule to produce 1.

Does this answer your question? How to properly use wildcards in input and output

When you say every input subset gets split into a fixed number, do you mean the number is defined before you start snakemake (e.g. like in your example each file gets split into two), or do you mean the number is depended on the file, test.py can split one file into 2 the other into 3, and so on.

I would say checkpoints are the way to go here. They allow you to reevaluate the dag within a run. In you case, checking the output of test.py and run the next rule accordingly.
The documentation covers a lot of possibilities, you might want to take a look at an example more relevant for you as well, e.g. here
Disclaimer: I never used them myself (always got away with a predefined config file), so take my advice with a grain of salt.
